# Help with using Direct Selection Tool while creating an icon in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, icon, corners

I am new to Illustrator and learning how to make icons following this link https://helpx.adobe.com/in/illustrator/how-to/icon-design.html

I am stuck at step 5. I am not getting the corner widget outside the shape as highlighted in the image on step 5. Because of this, I am unable to get inverted (outside) corners for the top rectangle.

So, my icon looks like this

[image: icon]

Comment: Looks like you missed out step 3 in the tutorial, where you combine the shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both rectangles are not merged, that's why when you make the round corners, the top rectangle gets rounded at the bottom.

[image: rectangle]

Selecting both shapes, use the **Pathfinder Panel** to **Unite** them and try again

[image: rectangle2]